# Graphical representation of door-open-door-closed data using chart.js

Tags: chart.js

Is there a way to graphically represent open and closed-door data using chart.js. An example with time series graph would be appreciated but also open to other ideas

Comment: The graphs I have seen tracking the state of a door, is generally a line graph with 2 values, 0 and 1 (closed and open). Example with highcharts: https://jsfiddle.net/uxptj6zs/